# SQL database, get data with changing conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I building a ferry system and I have three tables which are `Ports`, `Routes` and pivot table (`ports_of_route`) for relation. Ports table has `order` column that can be integer between 1-10. That gives me order of the port on route.

Now, I put the all ports from ports table to a select box, when user selected a port, I should get all ports which are possible to go from selected port (order number should be higher than selected order number for a route). But there's no specific route number, route not important for this.

An example, a ship's route may start from port-1 (order: 1, route_id: 2) and than port-2 (order: 2, route_id: 2), port-3 (order: 3, route_id: 2), port-4 (order: 4, route_id: 2). Another ship may start from port-3 (order: 1, route_id: 3) and goes to port-5 (order: 2, route_id: 3). These are different routes. When user selected the port-3, I should get port-4 and port-5.

I couldn't figure out that without making two query call. Can I do this in only one query?

Tables (unnecessary columns were not written):

```
    ports
    id   title
    1   port-1
    2   port-2
    3   port-3

..
```

````
```
routes
id   title
1   route-1
2   route-2
```
````

````
    ports_of_route
    port_id   route_id   order
    1         1          1
    2         1          2
    3         1          3
    2         2          1
    4         2          2
    ..
    ```

    Output: (port-2 selected)
    ```
    port_id ...
    3
    4
    ```
````

Comment: add your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select prnext.*
from ports_of_route pr join
     ports_of_route prnext 
     on prnext.order = pr.order + 1
where pr.port_id;
```

This uses the port ids and puts the results in separate rows.  If you want the port names, then you need additional joins:

```
select prnext.*, pnext.title
from ports_of_route pr 
     ports_of_route prnext 
     on prnext.order = pr.order + 1 join
     ports p
     on pr.port_id = p.id join
     ports pnext
     on prnext.port_id = pnext.port_id
where p.title = 'port-3';
```

Comment: thanks for answer but that gives the ports which only has next order. an example, can be 10 ports in one route and when I select port-3, that query gives me port-3 and port-4. I should get port-5,6,7,8 too. It can work if change the line `on prnext.order > pr.order join` but that gives duplicate datas.

Comment: @akcoban . . . "When user selected the port-3, I should get port-4 and port-5."  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.  Changing this question would be rude, because it would invalidate existing answers.

Comment: 'when user selected a port, I should get all ports which are possible to go from selected port' I wrote that. Only port-4 and 5 can be gets in my example. That's because of that sentence.

Comment: @akcoban . . . This question as written is more reasonably interpreted as the *next* port.  I would suggest that you ask another question.